# jQuery Serialize working intermittently with Bootstrap radio button group

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to serialize a radio-button when the Bootstrap `.btn` label is clicked.

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label label-default="" class="btn btn-primary">
        <input id="option1" name="options" type="radio" value="1">Option 1</label>
    <label label-default="" class="btn btn-primary active">
        <input id="option2" name="options" type="radio" value="1">Option 2</label>
    <label label-default="" class="btn btn-primary">
        <input id="option3" name="options" type="radio" value="1">Option 3</label>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".btn").on('click', function(){
  console.log("Name: " + $(this).children('input').attr('name') );
  console.log("Value: " + $(this).children('input').val() );
  console.log("Serialized: " +  $(this).children('input').serialize() );            
})
```

The name and value are always present in my output but the serialization works intermittently (sometimes returning the serialzed value and sometimes returing an empty string) and I can't figure out why.

Demo here: http://www.bootply.com/86422#

Thanks!

Comment: Your demo doesn't relate to the code in your question. I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qsMYR/) with your code and cannot produce the problem. Can you provide an example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: actually, adding the bootstrap js reproduced the problem. It is related to your selector and event: http://jsfiddle.net/qsMYR/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should really read ALL of the documentation on jQuery's `.serialize()` function if you are having issues.

### From the **[.serialize() API](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)** :

> Note: Only "successful controls" are serialized to the string. No submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted using a button. For a form element's value to be included in the serialized string, the element must have a name attribute. Values from checkboxes and radio buttons (inputs of type "radio" or "checkbox") are included only if they are checked. Data from file select elements is not serialized.

### Now from W3's documentation on [successful controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2) :

> For radio buttons that share the same value of the name attribute, only the "on" radio button may be successful.

All of that explains exactly why it works intermittently. Because sometimes you happen to `check` the radio button so it is considered `"on"` and your function serializes that input button.

### Here is a workaround :

Instead of using a input of type radio button, just use a plain input and set the display to none.

```
<div id="mode-group" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input name="mode" id="option1" value="cash/check" style="display: none">Cash / Cheque / Bank Transfer</label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input name="mode" id="option2" value="jobsBuddy" style="display: none">JobsBuddy Disbursement</label>
</div>
```

[Bootply Demo](http://www.bootply.com/czcjHcuf0I)

Comment: actually, if you remove the bootstrap.js reference it works, that would point to something intervening in bootstrap.

Comment: @CarrieKendall there is something funky going on there, and I wouldn't exclude this as a reason why. After all it does specifically reference radio buttons. If you go into the OPs bootply and wrap the input in `<form>` tags you can see the button

Comment: not saying this is wrong, but from the looks of it, probably irrelevant

Comment: @CarrieKendall That's not [what I'm seeing](http://jsfiddle.net/qsMYR/4/). Adjit would appear to be right, OP's "problem" is actually a feature.

Comment: @CarrieKendall you should look at your fiddle and see what happens when you click on the same element multiple times. Don't see how you can say this is irrelevant, when it clearly shows the OP is going against proper syntax

Comment: @pdoherty926 interesting about your fiddle... the event seems to bubble. Could be because of the bootstrap

Comment: @pdoherty926 i don't see any failures from that fiddle: [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/wHXVMMj.png). only when bootstrap.js is included.

Comment: @CarrieKendall the very first serialization fails because the button has not been checked yet. Using the workaround I just posted it serializes every time.

Comment: @Adjit thanks for the reply but the demo doesn't work. Clicking the same element multiple times doesn't always return the serialzed value even if the checked attribute is set to true.

Comment: @user1032752 are you looking at your console output? it says `Serialized: mode=on` it is the correct output. the syntax is `name=value`. Do you know how serialized works? have you listened to anything in my post or read any of the API?

Comment: @Adjit Are you clicking the button multiple times, 'cause the console says `Serialized:  `. Your post is interesting but doesn't answer the question. I'm still seeing intermittent times when the button is not serialized. Furthermore, removing the bootstrap reference seems to resolve the issue so I'm not sure how that can be irrelevant...

Comment: @user1032752 what buttons are you clicking?

Comment: @user1032752 It was working 100% perfectly for me yesterday, but now its back to intermittent. To prove my point, I have wrapped those buttons in a `<form>` tag, this way you can actually see the radio button. It behaves exactly as I stated, but also unsure as to why the workaround isn't working for me today... Look at this: http://www.bootply.com/B7pRHaHrK8

Comment: Tested in IE9 and Chrome 35.

Comment: @user1032752 look at the last comment I made. You can see that this IS the reason why it's not being serialized, but it's being funky because of something in bootstrap. Looking into a workaround

Comment: @Adjit you're probably right - it's a combination of both the missing attribute and bootstrap. I know bootstrap will set the radio button to checked when I click on the button. Can Bootstrap be reseting all the radio buttons in the group before activating the correct one and my event is firing when the button really is unchecked?

Comment: @user1032752 found your workaround... don't use a radio button : http://www.bootply.com/czcjHcuf0I

Comment: @Adjit - Not really, when the form is submitted via regular HTTP (non-AJAX) all three inputs are included. I could disable them but then would need JS to reenable them. Furthermore, I lose the BS functionality to have the corresponding input selected when I click a button.

Comment: @user1032752 - Well that is outside the scope of your question. I don't really know what you are trying to accomplish, but this way will allow your inputs to be serialized. You can also create your own 'serialize' function to accomplish what you want it to, and this way you don't have to include an `input` tag.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery `.serialize()` and `.serializeArray()` will only parse buttons which are checked. These are known as ["successful controls"](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2), as mentioned in the [jQuery documentation.](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

If you'd like to use a Bootstrap [button group](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/components/#btn-groups-single) where all buttons are unchecked (as seen in your question), then you should consider *"What if a user never checks any of the buttons?"*.

Therefore, you should include a hidden button which is checked by default, so that at least one of the buttons in your button group is parsed by `.serialize()` or `.serializeArray()`.

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">

    <!--
      This hidden checked button (with value 'none')
      will ensure that `serialize` parses at least one
      input in the button group.
    -->
    <input class="hidden" type="radio" name="color" value="none" checked>

    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="color" value="blue" />
        <span>Blue</span>
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="color" value="green" />
        <span>Green</span>
      </label>
    </div>

  </div>
</form>
```